# Should Bob sue a company on his home field?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, fraud, consumer-protection

Bob uncovers and obtains overwhelming evidence of several, major consumer exploitation ploys consisting of several distinct schemes, practices and policies of a major auto manufacturer of his new motor vehicle therethrough he personally was harmed, damaged or injured by the manufacturer.

Assume Bob has several counties of the same state where he a court would assume jurisdiction.

The manufacturer is of the size of any auto manufacturer.

There is some specific benefits to Bob filing suit in the county of the seller (i.e. it is also Bob's home county, it has the highest probability for exemplary damages be awarded etc.)

Considering the financial and political power of a major auto manufacturer and a primary employer as it typically the case in any county of any of these giants, how reasonable is it to file suit in state court and specifically do so in their home county?

Most attorneys advise that judges are really cold to such fraud cases while you would assume they are waiting for them "with open arms to hug and kiss you".

Would it be wiser to file in federal court or in another county? Are there any statistics about companies being sued and relieved in there home county vs. elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bob has to sue in a court of competent jurisdiction

To enliven jurisdiction, there has to be some connection between the parties or the event and the jurisdiction. Since Bob, the manufacturer and (presumably) the harmful incident all took place in County X, of State Y or Country A then they are the only jurisdictions that might be competent.

The courts of County Z, State M or Country B are all going to say "not my problem".

For the USA, there are only State courts and Federal courts. States may have courts that are *called* county courts but they are enlivened by the state sovereign - counties and cites are self-governing administrative districts, not sovereign states.

Federal courts have jurisdiction where the subject matter is about a Federal Statute, the Constitution or a treaty. This dispute would appear to be based on tort or contract law which is a state matter. Federal courts *can* have jurisdiction if the parties are in different states and the amount in dispute is more than $75,000. This would not appear to be the case.

So, as a state matter, the plaintiff can bring the case to any competent court. The defendant can apply to have it moved to a more convenient court. Arguments will be heard and, at some cost, you'll probably end up where you should have started.

Comment: Thank you, I specified the question further if you would be so kind and give consideration to it!